# Launching a Fragment after ZXing 2.0 QR-Code Scan

Tags: android, exception, android-fragments, qr-code, zxing

I've got some problems while launching a Fragment if i performed a QR-Code scan via the ZXing 2.0 library.

I got this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {fraiss.yucrowd/fraiss.yucrowd.activities.ScanQrCode}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState*
```

When i execute this code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.scan_qr_code);

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                // Handle successful scan
                Log.d("MENU", "Scan result: " + contents + " as " + format);

                // Load details for qr code
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();

                    Fragment fragmentDetails = new FragmentDetails(
                            contents);

                    fragmentTransaction
                            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_main,
                            fragmentDetails);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();  
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                // Handle cancel
                Log.d("MENU", "Scan canceled");
            }
        }
    }
```

I'am wondering why this happens. Is it not possible to launch a Fragment-Transaction at the end of a ActivityResult ?

Thx for your help in advance.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible for `onActivityResult` to be called before `onResume` and you can't add new fragments before the Activity has atleast called `onResume`.

Therefore you need to store the data you got in `onActivityResult`, check for this in `onResume` and perform your Fragment changes there.

Answer (score 2):

This basically happens because your activity is paused, with `onActivityResult` being called after `onSaveInstanceState`, hence the message: 'Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState'. Save away the requestCode, resultCode and intent and check in `onResume` if you have anything to work with.